# Sum of complex exponential signal in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, complex, damping

I want to create a sum of damped complex exponential signal with the known values of frequency $f$, damping $\alpha$, amplitude $a$ and phase $\phi$ for the $k = 1,2,...,K$ exponentials.  Is there already a command in MATLAB that does it? P.S. I have already written own function to do this.

\begin{equation}
    x_n = \sum_{k=1}^{K} (a_k e^{j\phi_k})(e^{\{(- \alpha_k + j2\pi f_k )\Delta t\}n}) + b_n, \quad n = 0,1,...,N-1 
\end{equation}

Comment: You can very easily write you own function if you wish. And use the vector notation for efficient generation without loops...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all about vectorization.

```
N = 8;
K = 10;
k = 1:K;            % row vector
f = k * 100;        % row vector
alpha = k / 10;     % row vector
a = k / 10;         % row vector
phi = k * pi;       % row vector

deltat = 1;

n = (0:N-1)';       % column vector
b = (1:N)';         % column vector

x = sum(a.*exp(1j*phi).*exp((-alpha+1j*2*pi*f)*deltat.*n)+b, 2);
```

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, I have this function written already, but I wanted to know whether there is any inbuilt function in MATLAB toolbox to do this.

Comment: @Neuling `S = sum(A,dim)` is exactly the built-in function which meets your demands. What more do you need?

Comment: I was looking for functions like chirp, sin, sawtooth etc, to generate signal for sum of exponentials. But I realized it is not available.  Thank you for your support